# Date in c# xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I have a date in XML:

```
<time>1340517600</time>
```

How can I convert it to a `DateTime` in C#?

Comment: Why is this question being voted down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for "Sun, 24 Jun 2012 06:00:00 GMT".

To convert from a Unix timestamp to a .NET DateTime, look at these questions:

- [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)
- [Parsing unix time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674215/parsing-unix-time-in-c-sharp)

Here is [Jon Skeet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674258/61974):

```
private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                      DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(string text)
{
    double seconds = double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return Epoch.AddSeconds(seconds);
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/XzLWX)