# How do you match various date formats using C# regex and get the day, month and year?

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

The known formats are listed below

```
dd/mm/yyyy (01/01/2015)
d/m/yyyy (1/1/2015)
dd/mm/yy (01/01/15)
d/m/yy (1/1/15)
```

Other variations will have dash(-), dot(.) or whitespace as field separator.

I am thinking of creating one regex per pattern to keep it maintainable but not sure if there is any better solution. Please share if there any better solution.

**Update:** 
The date is part of a large text and I cannot use DateTime.TryParseExact before extracting potential list of dates from the text.

Comment: I recommed you regex hero for try: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: You are using MVC Razor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse datetime in multiple formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859421/parse-datetime-in-multiple-formats)

Comment: In html5 there is input type datetime available.. which can handle all possible date formats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no knowledge about regex but, `DateTime.TryParseExact` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes formats as a string array.

You can easily supply all formats that you have and try your string is matched one of them or not.

By the way, [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes, [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months if you try to mentioned about months.

```
string s = "";
var formats = new string[]
{
             "dd/MM/yyyy",
             "d/M/yyyy",
             "dd/mm/yy",
             "d/m/yy",

             "dd-MM-yyyy",
             "d-M-yyyy",
             "dd-MM-yy",
             "d-M-yy",

             "dd.MM.yyyy",
             "d.M.yyyy",
             "dd.MM.yy",
             "d.M.yy",

             "dd MM yyyy",
             "d M yyyy",
             "dd MM yy",
             "d M yy",
};
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Your string is matched one of first successfull match
}
```

Comment: Thanks Soner. But that will not meet my requirement because the date will be part of a large text and I need to identify potential list of dates first before using the TryParseExact method.

Comment: @Mani Don't you have a chance to split this large string to get these values?

Comment: No, because the date can appear in any place in the string that I am parsing. This is why I am thinking of Regex to match various date patterns.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I have split the problem into two

- Identify Date Pattern in the string and extract the matched string
- Validate the identified date pattern and then extract day, month and year.

I am using regex to identify the pattern as follows and then using DateTime.TryParseExact to validate and extract day, month and year as suggested by Soner.

```
var datePatternRegex = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,2}(/|-|.|\s)\d{1,2}(/|-|.|\s)(\d{4}|\d{2})");
var testData = new []{
"This is test1 10/10/1012 data",
"This is test2 1/1/1012 data",
"This is test3 10-10-1012 data",
"This is test4 1-1-1012 data",
"This is test5 10.10.1012 data",
"This is test6 1.1.1012 data",
"This is test7 10 10 1012 data",
"This is test8 1 1 1012 data",
};

foreach(var data in testData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsing {0}", data);

    var match = datePatternRegex.Match(data);
    if(match.Success)
    {
        var result = match.Groups[0];
        Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```
        string input = "01/01/2015";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<day>(3[0-1]|[0-2]\d|\d))/(?<month>(1[0-2]|0\d|\d))/(?<year>([1-2]\d{3}|\d{2}))");
        Match match = regex.Match(input);

        string year = match.Groups["year"].Value;
        string month = match.Groups["month"].Value;
        string day = match.Groups["day"].Value;

        Trace.WriteLine(match.Groups["year"].Value);
        Trace.WriteLine(match.Groups["month"].Value);
        Trace.WriteLine(match.Groups["day"].Value);
```