# C# Parse DateTime using DateTime.TryParseExact() multiple format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing, tryparse

I have a `string text` that i want to parse/convert to DateTime,
the text can have a different formats (depending on the user who write it),
it can be "dd/MM/yyyy" or it can be "MM/dd/yyyy".

I am using `DateTime.TryParseExact(string, formats[], provider, dateTimeStyles, out result)`
as descripted here [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netstandard-2.0#system-datetime-tryparseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@))

Now the problem happens in the following cases
if (for example) `string text = "06/01/2023"`

The `text` could have two meanings
1<sup>st</sup>  -->  Day: **06**, Month: **01**, Year: 2023
2<sup>nd</sup> -->  Day: **01**, Month: **06**, Year: 2023

My Question is when does the Method `TryParseExact()` return `true`
does it return true for the **first** `format` that matches `text` ?
or does it evalute all/each format inside the `formats[]` array ?

i have tried to search for a similar question, but i didn't seem to find one,
i have tried read this reference [TryParseExactMultiple](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse.cs,a48a33b4d98f2af7)
i have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859421/parse-datetime-in-multiple-formats)

Thank you for your help in advance.

My code:

```
string text = "06/01/2023";

string[] formatsArray = new string[]
{
  "yyyyMMdd",
  "dd/MM/yyyy",
  "dd-MMM-yy",
  "MM/dd/yyyy",
  "MM-dd-yyyy"
};

DateTime result;

DateTime.TryParseExact(text, formatsArray, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```

Output is:
`result = Day: 06, Month: 01, Year: 2023`

Comment: Looks like it tries them in the order you present them. If you swap the order in formatsArray, what answer does it give?

Comment: It doesn't matter how `TryParseExact` works because there's no way for *humans* to say what the correct date is. This is why people should *not* use localized formats. Where does this string come from? A UI element? HTTP request? CSV file? Whatever creates the string should either be modified to use `DateTime` instead, or it should use the ISO8601 format.

Comment: @codeulike  
if I swap the order then `result = Day: 01, Month: 06, Year: 2023`  
but still, how do I know which format is used in the parsing?

Comment: @BolaAdelNassif it doesn't matter which one is used - even you can't guess what that date is without additional information. If you know what locale was used, instead of `TryParseExact` it's better to use `TryParse` with the correct locale.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse.cs,195) is pretty clear - `TryParseExact` calls `TryParseExactMultiple` which cycles formats in provided order and returns first one that succeeds:

```cs
internal static bool TryParseExactMultiple(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, string?[]? formats,
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style, scoped ref DateTimeResult result)
{
    // ...

    // Do a loop through the provided formats and see if we can parse successfully in
    // one of the formats.
    for (int i = 0; i < formats.Length; i++)
    {
        string? format = formats[i];
        // ...
        if (TryParseExact(s, format, dtfi, style, ref innerResult))
        {
            result.parsedDate = innerResult.parsedDate;
            result.timeZoneOffset = innerResult.timeZoneOffset;
            return true;
        }
    }

    result.SetBadDateTimeFailure();
    return false;
}
```

Since documentation does not specify behaviour for
I would not recommend to rely on it, if it is possible, or possibly wrap this into helper method which will be tested for your particular requirements.

In general - when accepting data from somewhere you need to agree on data format, if the source of the data is not under your control - contact the vendor to clarify it otherwise sooner or later the situation like this are bound to happen (in theory not only related to dates).

Comment: That doesn't answer the only question that matters - how to correctly parse such strings? The answer is good, the question is wrong.

Comment: `wrap this into helper method` Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netstandard-2.0#system-datetime-tryparseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@)), TryParseExact does not provide an indication for which format was used. My general recommendation is to allow users to send only one date format.

Comment: Thank you for your help, what if I take inputs from two different sources and each source has his own format and I don't know the format of each source?

Comment: @BolaAdelNassif you need to determine format for each of the sources and use different code to parse both.

Comment: @BolaAdelNassif I don't know your specific use case, but I could suggest either having different endpoints depending on the request source (if this is an API) or writing a function that tries several formats one by one and returns the successful format. Why do you need to know the format?