# Convert string type date input(yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ss) to MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I need to convert a date of string type in MM/dd/yyyy format and return year on some specific condition.My input string type date format can be also like (04/03/2023).But output should be only in MM/dd/yyyy format.
Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
 string dateformat= "2023-05-28t00:00:00";
    string yr = string.Empty;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateformat))
    {
     
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateformat, "MM/dd/yyyy",
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string currentResourceDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        int currentMon = int.Parse(currentResourceDate.Substring(0, 2));
        int cycleYear = currentMon >= 4 ? date.Year + 1 : date.Year;
        yr = Convert.ToString(cycleYear);
    }
```

But it is throwing some error as
'string '2023-05-28t00:00:00' was not recognized as a valid datetime.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse datetime in multiple formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859421/parse-datetime-in-multiple-formats)

Comment: That's what for. But how... `ParseExact` expects your input to be _exactly_ of the given format. Not the one you want in the end.

Comment: So wats appropriate way of doing this? i dont have control on input as its coming from different source

Comment: No, it is used to parse specific datetime format. You can specify the input format, and if it does not meet the format, an error will be returned.

Comment: i have mentioned in the description.can u plz have a look on that?

Comment: BTW: Why did you tag quite ancient C# versions? Are you maintaining C# code from the early 2000s?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `date of string type`.  `DateTime` is its own fully functional type,  And it doesnt have a format.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I guess OP meant to say "a date represented as formatted string". That's easily deductable from question. Give it some slack. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParseExact` expects you to give it the *exact* format your string-date *is in*.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider)):

> A format specifier that defines the required format of s.

Where "s" is the string-represented date argument.

In your case, that would be:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(formattedStringDate, "yyyy-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

In Action : https://dotnetfiddle.net/MiX7hx

---

On top of that, I'd like to suggest using `TryParseExact` which doesn't throw but gives you a boolean indicator of success / failure and the value in one go:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6pTTH

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var formattedDate = "2023-05-28t00:00:00";
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(formattedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extremely awkward US format: {0}", dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine("Current month: {0}", dateTime.Month);
            Console.WriteLine("Cycle year: {0}", dateTime.Month >= 4 ? dateTime.Year + 1 : dateTime.Year);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Extremely awkward US format: 05/28/2023
Current month: 5
Cycle year: 2024
```