# C# parse GMT date string to DateTime

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime

I'm using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ plugin to select date, and after date is selected I get e.g. `Fri Nov 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100`

1) Why am I getting that date format if I set up the plugin with format `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

2) How to parse `Fri Nov 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100` to DataTime with format `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

Comment: I assume that the datepicker returns a `Date` object. Wouldn't it be more convenient to pass it as unix time? `new Date().getTime()/1000`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674215/parsing-unix-time-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K"` format with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string s = "Fri Nov 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
10/31/2013 11:00:00 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/kTdo9S)</kbd>.

For more informations, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: it works - but what can you tell about the 1) question ? does that provided date format string depends on user's browser language/OS language. I'm trying figure out that because I want only one date format to be sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string GmtDateTimeString { get; set; }
     
    public static readonly string[] DateFormats =
    {
                "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    };

    public bool TryParseUtcDate(out DateTime d)
    {
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(GmtDateTimeString, DateFormats,
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out d))
                {
                    return true;
                }
    
                if (DateTime.TryParse(GmtDateTimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out d))
                {
                    return true;
                }
    
                d = DateTime.MinValue;
    
                return false;
   }
```